# sort dictionary of objects

Tags: python

I have a dictionary of objects where the key is a simple string, and the value is a data object with a few attributes.  I'd like to sort my dictionary based on an attribute in the values of the dictionary.  i have used this to sort based on the dictionaries values

```
sorted = dict.values()
sorted.sort(key = operator.attrgetter('total'), reverse=True)
```

This yields a sorted list of values (which is expected) and I lose my original keys from the dictionary (naturally).  I would like to sort both the keys and values together... how can I achieve this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: Don't call anything `dict`. It breaks stuff when trying to use the `dict()` builtin! If you cannot find a better name, call it `dct` or `dict_`.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, don't call anything `sorted` either.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `.items()` (or its iterator version `iteritems`) instead of `.values()` to get a list of `(key, value)` tuples.

```
items = sorted(dct.iteritems(), key=lambda x: x[1].total, reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use `.items()` rather than `.values()`, for example:

```
def keyFromItem(func):
    return lambda item: func(*item)

sorted(
    dict.items(), 
    key=keyFromItem( lambda k,v: (v['total'], k) )
)
```

The above will sort first based on total, and for items with equal total, will sort them alphabetically by key. It will return items as `(key,value)` pairs, which you could just do `[x[1] for x in sorted(...)]` to get the values.

Comment: What's with the higher-order function? Just `key=lambda (k,v): (v['total'], k)` (note parens in argument list) would work fine.

Comment: @larsmans: I wanted to, but destructuring arguments are being deprecated (Not that I personally dislike the concept; it is a common concept in other languages. However to use them would make the code not robust to future versions of python.) Sadly the justification for removing the feature is somewhat lacking: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/

Answer (score 1):

Use `items` instead of `values` - and a just use a lambda to fecth the sorting key itself, since there won't be a ready made `operator`  for it:

```
sorted = dict.items()
sorted.sort(key = lambda item: item[1].total, reverse=True)
```